Libclang way slower to parse AST than -ast-dump option
I'm generating code by parsing the AST of my header files with libclang and I'm experiencing very long parsing time (30+ seconds on every files). I've tried -ast-dump=json and it's way faster. I start getting output in the terminal under one second and it takes a few seconds to dump the AST to a JSON file.
Here is a minimal example of my code with libclang:
struct ast_parser
{
    CXIndex index;

    ast_parser()
    {
        index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    }

    ~ast_parser() noexcept
    {
        clang_disposeIndex(index);
    }

    bool parse(std::string_view path, ast& out_ast)
    {
        constexpr CXTranslationUnit_Flags flags =
            static_cast<CXTranslationUnit_Flags>(
                CXTranslationUnit_Incomplete |
                CXTranslationUnit_SkipFunctionBodies |
                CXTranslationUnit_SingleFileParse |
                CXTranslationUnit_KeepGoing);
            
        std::vector<const char*> args {
            "-xc++",
            "-std=c++20",
            // only an example, actual values generated from CMake file 
            "-Iproject/include",
            "-Ivcpkg/include",
            "-DCODEGEN=1",
        };
                
        CXTranslationUnit translation_unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
            index, path.data(), args.data(), static_cast<int>(args.size()), nullptr, 0, flags);
        
        if (translation_unit == nullptr)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        CXCursor cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(translation_unit);
        CXCursorVisitor visitor = [](CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData data) {
            // ...
        };
        
        clang_visitChildren(cursor, visitor, nullptr);
        clang_disposeTranslationUnit(translation_unit);
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ast ast;
    ast_parser parser;
    return parser.parse("file.hpp", ast) ? 0 : -1;
}

Here is the command line I use to dump the AST to JSON:
clang++ -Xclang -ast-dump=json -Xclang -fsyntax-only -std=c++20 -Iproject/include -Ivcpkg/include -DCODEGEN=1 file.hpp > file.hpp.json

Is there any way with libclang or libtooling to parse the AST and get the same performances as the command line?

Is this a release build of libclang?

I've tried both and both are slow

@Jazzwave06 Actual timings for both release and debug builds of libclang might help.  Part of the problem here is that what you are saying sort of doesn't make sense: so it is going to be some detail of your configuration or libclang's configuration that causes your problem.  But without a full [mcve], anyone trying to help you is either going to have to "get lucky" or reproduce everything you did and make the same mistakes.  Including a minimal header file that causes the speed difference might also be useful (minimal; so, ~2 seconds in your code, <0.1 seconds via ast-dump)

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I've created a small repository that reproduces the issue: https://github.com/sturcotte06/libclang-issue. You can replace detail::clang_exec with your path to clang++ executable and you can remove LLVM from vcpkg.json and add the absolute path to libclang.lib directly in target_link_libraries instead of downloading + compiling LLVM with vcpkg. It took 30s with libclang and 1s with dump-ast.
